# How to secure JWT token

Tags: security, jwt, postman, token, access-token

If a token is stored in the local storage or a cookie, another user might be able to copy the token from one PC and use it on their own PC. How can this security issue be addressed?

I want user not access or copy our jwt Token and use it in another pc

Comment: The security risk is not that users might clone _their own_ tokens (which I don't consider the worst security issue in the world), but that any JavaScript in a page (ads, XSS attacks, sneaky bookmarklets and dodgy browser-extensions, and the rest...) are also able to get them. Ultimately, there is no way to keep secrets secure in a browser-based scenario, that's why SPAs are dead and people now use reverse-proxies to hold secrets (via encrypted HTTP-only cookies, which are far less suspectible to exfiltration).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know perfect solution does not exist. You could try to get some unique info on user’s machine to be included in JWT. But that is not always doable, and it might affect user experience. Here is some option you could try:

- IP address: if IP address was changed, ask user to login again
- User agent: same as IP address
- Geolocation

Comment: All major browsers froze their User-Agent headers years ago, making it useless for purposes like this (which is a good thing).